# Trying to deserialize JSON into Dictionary<string, List<string>> in c#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize JSON into a dictionary with strings as keys and lists of strings as values. The way I did it is this:

```json
[
    {
        "key1": [
            "value1.1",
            "value1.2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "key2": [
            "value2.1",
            "value2.2"
        ]
    },
]
```

and to deserialize:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary;
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"Text.json");
dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(text);
```

I am receiving the errors:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Does anyone have have any insights for me?

Comment: The type in your file is `Dictionary<string, List<string>>[]` not `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: Try to deserialize into `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`

Comment: Can one of you add that as the answer then?

Comment: You could deserialize the json to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>[]` and add some **Linq** to get `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, like `Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>[]>(json).SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution As Per Question:**

Try this, Hopefully this will help you. https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3u1TC

```
string json = @"[{""key1"":[""value1.1"",""value1.2""]},{""key2"":[""value2.1"",""value2.2""]}]";
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>[]>(json);
```

**Edit**

**Updated Solution:**

If you don't need an array. Then you have to update your json. Remove array braces `[]` and add these ones `{}`

**Json**

```
{
    {
        "key1": [
            "value1.1",
            "value1.2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "key2": [
            "value2.1",
            "value2.2"
        ]
    },
}
```

**C#**

```
string json = @"{""key1"":[""value1.1"",""value1.2""],""key2"":[""value2.1"",""value2.2""]}";
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
```

Comment: I might not not understand how Json works but my intention is to make a single dictionary of list of strings. Not an array of dictionaries. Is what I am doing wrong for that or is it just not possible to do it this simply?

Comment: Your data structure shown in the JSON does not match what you're after. The actual structure you've got is an array of dictionaries.

You'd have to deserialise what it actually is first, then merge the resulting dictionaries afterwards.

Comment: @ארזגולן We create data structure based on your Json. In Json structure you have An array of object and each object contain string Property Name and array so technically it's an array that contains string and array on each index.

Answer (score 0):

JSON syntax for dictionary is `{ "key1": "val1", "key2: "val2".....}`

So if your JSON is structured as follows, your conversion will work as it is.

```
string json = @"{""key1"":[""value1.1"",""value1.2""],""key2"":[""value2.1"",""value2.2""]}";
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
```